# C++03: Is there a way to make a type that will compile to different types every time it is included in a template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, hash, types, c++03

I am trying to achieve something like this:

```
typeof(vector<MyStrangeType>) != typeof(vector<MyStrangeType>)
```

I.e. I want this type to produce a different type every time it is included as a template parameter.

An example of where I might practically want this is to avoid undefined behavior in this situation:

```
class DeviousHashAlg {
  private:
    int seed;
  public
    DeviousHashAlg() {
        seed = rand();
    }
    template<class TYPE>
    size_t operator()(TYPE key) {
        return hash<TYPE>()(key) * seed
    }
}

unordered_map<SomeKey, SomeValue, DeviousHashAlg> map1;
unordered_map<SomeKey, SomeValue, DeviousHashAlg> map2;

map1 == map2; // Currently undefined
```

It is undefined behavior to compare these maps, since the values inside will not have hashed to the same bucked. What I would like to do is make this undefined behavior instead a compile time error. This is why I want `DeviousHashAlg` to produce a different type every time it is included in a template like `unordered_map`, so that we won't be allowed to use `==`.

Is this even possible? I'd prefer to use language support if possible, though I suspect some pre-processing black magic may be the only solution.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the term "undefined behavior" correctly?

Comment: If `==` is your **only** worry - you can just explicitly tell the compiler to treat this as error: `inline bool operator==(const & unordered_map<SomeKey, SomeValue, DeviousHashAlg> _lhs, const & unordered_map<SomeKey, SomeValue, DeviousHashAlg> _rhs){#error illegal!}`

Comment: I believe I am, however, I am new to the world of C++ so I may have miss used it. Would you mind clarifying what you think is wrong with my statement and how I can correct it?

Comment: `DeviousHashAlg` isn't a [valid hash](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash).

Comment: @Pradhan You are right that it does not meet the requirements of `std::hash`, however, it is not a specialization of `std::hash`. `DeviousHashAlg` is instead a whole new hashing algorithm, which if it was actually properly fleshed out would have a desirable property of being able to thwart hash table DOS attacks (I'm well aware that in its current incarnation it does not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the macro `__COUNTER__` and make your class template as follow:

```
template <std::size_t N>
struct DeviousHashAlg
{
/* Your code */
};

#define UNIQUE_DeviousHashAlg DeviousHashAlg<__COUNTER__>
```

And then, for

```
unordered_map<SomeKey, SomeValue, UNIQUE_DeviousHashAlg> map1;
unordered_map<SomeKey, SomeValue, UNIQUE_DeviousHashAlg> map2;
```

`map1` and `map2` will have different type.

Comment: Note: `__COUNTER__` is a compiler extension, not defined by standard

Comment: @icepack: true, but at least msvc, gcc, and clang support it.

Comment: Yep. Actually, I intended to write exactly the same answer, but you beat me by 5 mins :)

Comment: It might not matter for GBleaney's purposes, but I think `__COUNTER__` starts from 0 with each translation unit, so this could cause all kind of havoc if used across translation units (e.g. types in headers would be seen different by clients and the header's implementation file, unintended repeats....)